LM13700: gm tracking and forward transconductance
In the datasheet of the LM13700, it states that the Forward transconductance (\$g_m\$) has the following specifications for a given bias/tail current:

Minimum: \$6{,}700 \ \mu S\$
Typical: \$9{,}700 \ \mu S\$
Maximum: \$13{,}000 \ \mu S\$

The next line mentions a \$g_m\$ tracking of 0.3 dB.
Can someone explain what these two values exactly mean? I haven’t been able to find much information on this topic online.
From my understanding:

The \$g_m\$ of the OTA can vary between \$6{,}700 \ \mu S\$ and \$13{,}000 \ \mu S\$ for a given bias current. This seems like a significant variation.
For example, if I were to design a voltage-controlled state-variable filter and supply both voltage-controlled integrators with the same bias current, the gain could potentially vary by an octave due to this \$g_m\$ variation.

Am I interpreting this correctly?

The \$g_m\$ tracking specification means that if you apply the same bias current of 500µA to both channels of the LM13700, their gains will differ by at most 0.3 dB. In other words: The gain of the LM13700 may vary a lot, but the two amps within the package will always vary by (almost) exactly the same amount.
There's one electrical characteristic that gives away why the gain can vary so much: The peak output current at \$I_{ABC}\$ = 500 µA. This specification is measured with the input stage in saturation, steering \$I_{ABC}\$ fully down either the inverting or non-inverting path within the IC until it gets to the output, which renders the \$g_m\$ of the input stage totally irrelevant. The gain of this path, which is made up of a bunch of current mirrors, can vary enough for those 500µA to turn into anything between 350µA and 650µA. The ratio between the extreme values for the peak output current and for \$g_m\$ is almost identical (approximately 1.9), which indicates that the variation in both is caused almost entirely by imperfect current mirror gain.
The path from the \$I_{ABC}\$ input pin to the output consists of up to three cascaded current mirrors (going via the inverting input transistor). Let's assume that each current mirror's gain can be off by \$\pm10\%\$, which is quite typical. At the low end, this results in an overall gain of the three cascaded stages of \$0.9^3 = 0.729\$, and at the high end, it's \$1.1^3 = 1.331\$.
Multiplying our nominal 9600 µS transconductance with these two factors gives us 6998 µS and 12777 µS, respectively. Similarly, if we multiply our 500µA nominal peak output current with the same values, we get 364µA and 665µA. Those are all almost exactly the datasheet minima and maxima! So with that, we can be quite sure that it's the current mirrors that cause this variation in gain, not the input stage.
If you want your state-variable filter to be precise, you'll need to calibrate the circuit and potentially even apply temperature compensation if the ambient temperature can vary significantly.
You could alternatively use a digital potentiometer followed by a buffer and OpAmp integrator if you want it to be more precise without calibration.

Thank you! Do you know the source of this variation? Considering the use of BJTs and that the transistors are likely manufactured on a single die, I would expect the gain (gm) to be tightly controlled. Mathematically, the Ebers-Moll model—while simplified—is still quite accurate at low frequencies, and my mathematical derivation of the gain equation (Eq 5. in the datasheet) doesn’t seem to reveal any severe enough simplifications that would account for such variation. the only thing that comes to mind is the temperature, but the specification is stated for a given ambient temperature.

@rootsroots The LM13700 doesn't only contain the differential input transistors. There's also a bunch of current mirrors inside, which don't necessarily have perfect unity gain. TI also likely just specifies gm loosely to have some safety margin, though.

@rootsroots I've updated the answer with some detailed datasheet detective work. Let me know if anything else is unclear!

Thank you so much for your effort, Jonathan! That makes a lot of sense. :)
